# Node.js: Executing a file from the CLI

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

Using Linux, I can run a Javascript file with `node file.js`. Is it possible to run `file.js` after entering the Node CLI using `node`?

Comment: I don't believe you can... not directly anyway.

Comment: It'd help if you'd explain what you're trying to accomplish. But, you can `exec` it again from the Node repl or use the `vm` module in Node core: http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This is actually possible with the REPL functions, specifically`.load`. This loads the script into the current terminal, allowing for terminal input for debugging rather than resuming stdin.

The REPL commands can be accessed with `.help`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this.

What you can do is use `require` and you can make your file behave differently whether it is running standalone or used by `require`, which gives you almost what you are looking for.

From the CLI:

```
mod = require("my_module);
mod.my_function();
```

To figure if you are running standalone, use a test like this: `require.main === module`

So file.js becomes:

```
function my_function() {
  ...
}

exports.my_function = my_function;

if (require.main === module) {
  // I'm running standalone
  my_function();
}
```